# Minikube installation on RHEL

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

Running Minikube on Linux box with --vm-driver=none and the cluster setup is completely successful. But while running kubectl commandsto get deployments or pods its giving error "Tunnel Connection Failed" (max limit for the opening files on the Linux box is set).

Comment: Are you on VPN? Minikube does not work properly on VPN. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/48725962/8645590.

Comment: @VikramHosakote or rather some VPN solutions try to tunnel all traffic over the VPN and thus making your local VMs not reachable.

Comment: I’m not running any vpn solution on the same box.